# Gulp Not Finishing a Task

Tags: javascript, gulp, babeljs

My `build` task never calls the `copy:build task` because it looks like the `transpile` task doesn't return (I never see "Finished" for the transpile task in the console), so it never continues onto the last task:

```
require('babel-core/register');

var gulp = require('gulp'),
  less = require('gulp-less'),
  uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
  babel = require("gulp-babel"),
  shell = require('gulp-shell'),
  mocha = require('gulp-mocha'),
  runSequence = require('run-sequence'),
  browserify = require('gulp-browserify'),
  rename = require('gulp-rename'),
  del = require('del');

require('dotenv').config();

const { env } = process;

gulp.task('build', function (done) {
  runSequence('clean', 'transpile', 'copy:build', done);
});

gulp.task('clean', function () {
  return del(['./build', './dist']);
});

gulp.task('transpile', function () {
  return gulp.src(['./src/**/*.js', '!./src/client/less/*.js'])
    .pipe(babel())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("build"));
});

gulp.task('copy:build', function () {
  return gulp.src(['src/shared/**/*.json']).pipe(gulp.dest('build/shared'));
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dist": "gulp dist",
    "start": "node dist/server.js",
    "postinstall": "yarn run dist",
    "test-backend": "gulp build && gulp spec-backend",
    "test-frontend": "gulp build && yarn run flow && gulp spec-frontend",
    "test-all": "gulp build && spec-all",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production gulp build",
    "local": "NODE_ENV=development gulp dist && npm start"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/me/my-app.git"
  },
  "author": "Me",
  "license": "",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/me/my-app/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/me/my-app#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "browserify": "^16.2.3",
    "compression": "^1.7.3",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.5.0",
    "core-js": "^2.6.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "del": "^3.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^6.2.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "gulp-cli": "^2.0.1",
    "gulp-if": "^2.0.2",
    "gulp-less": "^4.0.1",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.4.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "nock": "^10.0.5",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-addons-create-fragment": "^15.6.2",
    "react-compat": "^0.0.1",
    "react-document-title": "^2.0.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-ga": "^2.5.6",
    "react-grid-gallery": "^0.5.3",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.1",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scroll": "^1.7.10",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "superagent": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/cli": "^7.1.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-preset-flow": "^6.23.0",
    "babelify": "^10.0.0",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.8.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.7.1",
    "eslint": "^5.11.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.0",
    "flow-bin": "^0.89.0",
    "flowtypify": "^1.0.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-babel": "^8.0.0",
    "gulp-browserify": "^0.5.1",
    "gulp-bundle-assets": "^2.29.0",
    "gulp-mocha": "^6.0.0",
    "gulp-shell": "^0.6.5",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp-wait": "^0.0.2",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "jsdom": "^13.1.0",
    "mocha": "^5.2.0",
    "postcss": "^7.0.7",
    "postcss-cli": "^6.1.0",
    "run-sequence": "^2.2.1",
    "sinon": "^7.2.2",
    "supertest": "^3.3.0",
    "watchify": "^3.11.0"
  }
}
```

Here's the output I see in the console, notice you don't see "Finished" for the transpile task which is why it never runs the "copy:build" task:

[image]

So what happens is brings me back to the console after the last line `Starting 'transpile'...` as if it is done but it's obviously not, because it didn't show finished nor did it ever run my `copy:build` task.

Tried running the copy:build task directly, works fine.  The problem is with the transpile script never even getting here:

[image]

Comment: .pipe(gulp.dest('/build')); with a slash to create the directory or does the build folder exist after the crash?

Comment: yes that creates the directory successfully.  So I think it's at least getting to `.pipe(gulp.dest("build"));` which does create the build folder

Comment: I added an animated gif to illustrate it better

Comment: tried it, that gave me the same problem with clean, it starts cleaning but never finished the cleaning.  My original clean task seems to be fine.

Comment: resolved see below

Comment: Glad you found it and that you added the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I had to remove the return:

```
gulp.task('transpile', function () {
  gulp.src(['./src/**/*.js', '!./src/client/less/*.js'])
    .pipe(babel())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("build"));
});
```